# On linux, how to make sure to unlock a mutex which was locked in a thread that dies/terminates?

Tags: linux, multithreading, locking, mutex

This is an interview question.

On linux, how to make sure to unlock a POSIX mutex which was locked in a POSIX  thread that dies/terminates?

My idea:

Linux will release it automatically when it send kill or termination signal to the program ? But, I cannot find more details about how OS do this ?

thanks

Comment: Any more context? How is the thread killed exactly?

Comment: How is the mutex implemented? POSIX, or SysV semaphores?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A **robust mutex** can be used to handle the case where the owner of the mutex is terminated while holding the mutex lock, so that a deadlock does not occur.  These have more overhead than a regular mutex, and require that all clients locking the mutex be prepared to handle the error code `EOWNERDEAD`.  This indicates that the former owner has died and that the client receiving this error code is the new owner and is responsible for cleaning up any inconsistent state.

A robust mutex is a mutex with the robust attribute set.  It is set using the POSIX.1-2008 standard function [`pthread_mutexattr_setrobust(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.html).

Further details and example code can be found on [the Linux manual page for `pthread_mutexattr_getrobust`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_mutexattr_getrobust.3.html).

Answer (score 3):

If it's not a process-shared mutex, it doesn't matter. When one thread dies, the process dies, and the mutex goes away.

If it's a process-shared mutex, you're asking the wrong question. You wouldn't *want* to unlock the mutex if a thread died while holding it. The reason a thread holds a mutex is so that it can manipulate shared data through states that must not be seen by other threads. If a thread dies while holding a mutex, it is likely that the data was left in such an inconsistent state. Unlocking the mutex would just allow other threads to see the invalid/corrupt data.

Comment: I couldn't articulate my thoughts in my own mind, but something just didn't seem to make sense about this question. You hit the nail on the head, imho.

Comment: I guess there's always the scenario when the thread exits cleanly but a programmer's error left a mutex locked. Surely you'd want to recover from this, if possible. It must be that I haven't done the right type of programming yet, being that I've never encountered this.

Comment: @SanJacinto There's no way you could know that this was the error, as opposed to leaving the data protected by the mutex in an inconsistent state. You have to assume the shared data is corrupt. You can handle this case, but it requires code that can either repair any problems with the shared data or not try to and operate without the shared data (possibly by shutting down as cleanly as possible and restarting).

Comment: There is a usecase when it's justified - when a mutex protects not the state itself, but some rather meta information about the state. Imagine a number of applications working on a single file - the file itself might be operated in an atomic way, but to ensure that each process operates on up-to-date state (i.e. there is no other process currently working on a file modification) - you need to make a standard R/W lock. If someone's holding a lock is dead - that's just it. File wasn't written, state is ok. You may resume your operations.

Comment: @AndrianNord Sure, but that's not likely to be helpful in answering the question the OP asked. An interviewer asking such a general question is going to be interested in answers for typical use cases, not ones so rare that they may never have occurred. (And advisory file locks exist for that use case.)