# pthread_mutex_lock and an abandoned shared mutex

Tags: c, macos, freebsd, bsd, launch-daemon

Pardon me if I'm asking the obvious. I come from years of programming under Windows.

Currently I'm working on a project that is running under macOS. (And I believe it uses Free BSD under the hood.)

So I need to synchronize access to a shared resource from multiple processes (one is a launch daemon and others are client processes.)

I chose to do so using a shared (named) mutex.

I couldn't see any direct implementation of a named mutex by the kernel. All I could find were implementations that used shared memory, that went as such:

1. Create/open a shared memory segment, either with `shm_open` or with `shmget`+`shmat`
2. Use a regular `pthread_mutex_t` but initialize it with attributes: `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mtxAtt, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);`
3. Then create it as a regular mutex: `pthread_mutex_init`
4. And use it to lock and unlock with `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock`.

This works, except for one edge case:

Say, a client acquires this shared mutex with a call to `pthread_mutex_lock`, and then either crashes, or is terminated by a user, thus it never calls `pthread_mutex_unlock`. (In Microsoft parlance they call the state that that mutex would be in, an ["abandoned" mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.abandonedmutexexception?view=net-7.0). And in their case, if another process tries to acquire such mutex, this will result in an error from a locking function to denote the situation.)

In my case though, for macOS, if my launch daemon tries to call `pthread_mutex_lock` on the same shared mutex (after it became "abandoned"), it will deadlock forever.

Thus, I'm wondering, if there is a way to determine if a mutex is in such "abandoned" state? (and avoid a deadlock of locking such a mutex and potentially deadlocking the thread.)

---

EDIT: While trying to understand how to use System V semaphore, as an IPC mutex, suggested in the comments, I was able to find the following code snippet (using AI):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
```

To init:

```
key_t key = ftok("/tmp/semfile", 1);
if (key < 0) {
    perror("ftok");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int semid = semget(key, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
if (semid < 0) {
    perror("semget");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// initialize the semaphore with a value of 1
if (semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, 1) < 0) {
    perror("semctl");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Then to enter mutex:

```
struct sembuf sops = { 0, -1, SEM_UNDO };

// acquire the semaphore (lock)
if (semop(semid, &sops, 1) < 0) {
    perror("semop");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

and to leave it:

```
sops.sem_op = 1;

// release the semaphore (unlock)
if (semop(semid, &sops, 1) < 0) {
    perror("semop");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

And finally, cleanup:

```
// destroy the semaphore
if (semctl(semid, 0, IPC_RMID) < 0) {
    perror("semctl");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The problem though, that it works only in the same process. For the IPC case, I can enter and leave as if the semaphores in each process are not connected to each other.

What is missing there?

Comment: The process could still crash after you did the test while waiting for unlock so that would just introduce a TOCTOU bug.

Comment: You might want to look at the traditional System V named semaphore API (sys/sem.h; not to be confused with POSIX semaphore.h); IIRC it had *something* for this situation.

Comment: @zwol: can you give me more details? Or at least, which function are you referring to?

Comment: [semop](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semop.2.html) and in particular the SEM_UNDO mechanism.

Comment: _Side note:_ AFAIK [and I could be wrong about this], macOS is based on `mach` [Carnegie Mellon] but, in addition to APIs from Next [cocoa?], it has an integrated FreeBSD syscall API.

Comment: @CraigEstey In that case, do you know if `mach` has an implementation of the IPC mutex?

Comment: @zwol: I'm having trouble figuring out how to use `SEM_UNDO mechanism` for an IPC mutex (with the use of that semaphore). It'd be nice if you can show it with code.

Comment: See: [Equivalent of Windows's named mutex in Mac OS X? (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23920757/5382650) and [On linux, how to make sure to unlock a mutex which was locked in a thread that dies/terminates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9198799/5382650) and https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.html

Comment: @CraigEstey: I don't know how that code from your first link can work in an IPC setting for a macOS. It doesn't even compile. But if we rearrange the placement of `pthread_mutex_t* mutex;`, it will use what I described above in my OP. Additionally, I can't use `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST_NP` for macOS. There's no such constant defined, nor `pthread_mutexattr_setrobust_np` function in macOS. My guess is that people from the Linux OS upvoted it. Unless I don't understand something, do I?

Comment: @CraigEstey Much of macOS userland is from FreeBSD userland. You are right about mach though some of FreeBSD is in their kernel, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I spent 3 days trying to do [what on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexexa) would've taken me less than an hour.

**My conclusion:** macOS does not have a reliable IPC mutex.

---

So if someone finds a solution that meets the criteria that I outlined above, I'll be glad to hear it.

I investigated so far:

- POSIX mutexes via `pthread_mutex_t` and a shared memory (like I showed above) lack one critical function: `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST_NP` or `pthread_mutexattr_setrobust_np`. Without them, they act just like semaphors.
- Named semaphores exist (via `sem_open`) but they lack the basic need to protect against a dead process that doesn't unlock them (abandoned mutex issue that I described in my OP.)
- System V evidently provides means to safeguard against unexpectedly terminated process via the `SEM_UNDO` flag (like I showed in my OP) but I failed to find a way to make it work across processes. And the documentation (for this stuff) is abysmal to say the least.
- In total desperation to find a solution, I even tried to use "abstract UNIX domain sockets", that are supposedly closed automatically if a process dies. Something as someone had [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37256347/843732). But guess what, macOS does not seem to support them and the `bind` function simply returns `errno` 2.
- I then thought to implement my own mutex via shared memory, by keeping a thread ID of the locking process in it. But again, there's no synchronization principals to work across processes. For instance, there's no such thing as a named event. One can use a named semaphore for it, but that brings me back to the limitation I named earlier.
- Lastly, this absolutely idiotic design pattern when one needs to call `unlink` to remove a named object besides calling `close` on it totally removes any possibility of a robust implementation. For instance, if one process crashes, it leaves a named object in an undefined state for the next process that wants to use it: how would it know what happened? Is the named object still being used? Or is it simply abandoned. The only way to remedy this "for sure" is to restart the macOS. Which is totally bunkers!

I am really baffled by my discovery, as there should be synchronization objects that work across processes. How do they write their OS? Or, everyone is just using files and then has to `unlink` them? No wonder sometimes I have to restart my Mac to fix some issue in an app.

Comment: *macOS does not have a reliable IPC mutex.*  You can actually do much **better** on POSIX systems than Windows.  Use a [robust mutex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.html) in shared memory.  So if a process dies for any reason while holding the lock you can actually fix it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: please read what I said above. I am not comparing Linux to Windows.

Comment: *I am not comparing Linux to Windows.*  **Oh yes you are**:  *OK, so I spent 3 days trying to do what on Windows would've taken me less than an hour.*

Comment: Nevermind *macOS does not have a reliable IPC mutex* is factually incorrect to begin with.

Comment: `How do they write their OS` : good question. Friendly speaking, you spend 3 days trying something, try sleeping one day could provide some help too. From what I see here, you need a Thread Manager that will dispatch some task (in your case, as processes) ; pretty sure you'll find a Design pattern on this ; last, not sure AI will shed some light on this. BR

Comment: @ValeryS. Andrew, if you guys want to prove me wrong, post an answer here. Words is one thing - working code is another. (Again, I'm talking about IPC mutex on macOS that doesn't deadlock threads in some edge cases. Nothing else.)

Comment: Did you ever get a reliable solution to this? Like you, I've been struggling with edge cases on MacOS with named mutexes that can be set up on Windows in less than an hour. The main problem being the lack of support for a robust mutex on MacOS, and the absolutely insane requirement to unlink shared memory objects which is impossible to do if your process is killed...

Comment: @BrandonStaggs: it's been a while, but if I remember correctly, I wasn't able to find a reliable solution. If you do, please share it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You mention robust mutex. All the documentation I can find says this is not supported on MacOS. Can you suggest how to set up a robust mutex on MacOS?

Comment: @c00000fd I ended up using a file locking mechanism (with mapping) since the OS will clean up open file descriptors when a process is killed. It is not a true mutex obviously and is not appropriate for all use cases. Like you, I am astonished that there is no good low-level approach to this on MacOS when every other OS has figured this out.

Comment: @BrandonStaggs yep, quite astounding. If you have some free time, do you post your solution?